# TextArea, process each character one at a time

Tags: qt, qml

I have a text area and I want to listen to every characters inputted on it,
What I am trying to do is when a spacebar is pressed, I will perform an operation or processing such as replacing some characters on it.
I have tried and listen to onTextChanged however, it may cause recursion as setting my TextArea.text to new value triggers a call to onTextChange event thus causing Stack Overflow.

I have tried to listen to Keys.onPressed event as well and listen to space key but the space key is processed as well and when I set a new text value, the space value is forcedly inserted.
How and where should I handled and listen to these events?

1. How can I listen to each inputted characters in QML text area, catch the space bar, process, and replace the text with the new processed text? Also ignore the last spacebar entry?
2. How do I reject a chracter when inputted in the TextEdit or TextArea?

Comment: Why don't you use `QSignalBlocker` when processing the text to avoid the endless recursion?

Comment: You can write your own QValidator, where you have to override QValidator::validate(QString &input, int &pos) const method. If you modify the input string, then, it will replace the text written by the user as well. This approach involves C++, but you have the most control over it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `TextInput` which helps you differ whether text is changed by user or programmatically ?

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    TextInput
    {
        width: 200
        height: 100

        onTextEdited:
        {
            if( text[text.length-1] === " " )
            {
                text = process(text)
            }
        }

        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }


    function process(textinput)
    {
        return textinput.toUpperCase()
    }
}
```